# Dimension of the quotient of a local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

Let ($R$ , $$) be a local Noetherian ring. Suppose that $I=(x_1,..., x_k) \subseteq  $. Is it true that 
$\dim R/I=\dim R-k$ ?

Thank you.

Comment: No, it's not.${}$

Comment: @user26857 Thank you. Is there a counterexample?

Comment: Plenty. $\dim K[X,Y]_{(X,Y)}/(X^2,XY)=1$.

Comment: Trivial example: take $x_i=0$ for all $i$. Little less trivial: take all the $x_i$ in the nilradical. In both cases, dim $R$ = dim $R/I$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As referenced in the comments, this is not true in general. In fact, it happens exactly when $(x_1,...,x_k)$ forms part of a [system of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_parameters).

Answer (score 1):

It is not true in general. You can prove this one:

- $\dim( R/I )\ge \dim( R)-k$
- $(x_{1},...,x_{k})$ is part of a system of parameters iff $\dim (R/I)= \dim( R) - k$